# IntelliJ/WebStorm "Smart" Indenting / Tab on newline

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

So this seems like quite a trivial question.
At the moment when declaring an object, and assigning values as such:

```
let object = {
    myValue: "some value" <--- Now typically here I would hit <comma> <enter>
}
```

What use to happen:

```
let object = {
    myValue: "some value",
    anotherValue: "some other value"
}
```

What is happening now:

```
let object = {
    myValue: "some value",
        anotherValue: "some other value" <--- What is with this additional tabspace?
}
```

It's driving me nuts, and it's such a weird and specific thing to explain, google to no avail!

Every time I declare object properties I have to `<shift> <tab>` this additional space or `<backspace>`. Seriously driving me nuts, completely destroys my grove. This has been included in the new WebStorm update (2017.2).

Where is the setting to change this? What do I call this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it sorted.
So it's very specific to the following conditions:

1. You're editing a file that has `x` spaces on `indents / tabs`
2. Your default `indent / tab spacing` is `y`

Webstorm, assumes you want to apply: `y` indent / tab spaces when hitting your tab key, or creating a newline on a tabbed / indented element. So it applies `y` indent spaces. But it also recognises that the file has `x` spaces per indent.

The result is, when you hit tab on a indented element, it will indent by `x` spaces and when you create a newline on a indented element, it indent by `y` spaces.

To change this, you can either configure Webstorm to tab by `x` spaces, or configure it's dynamic file tab / indent space detection.

**To disable Indent / Tab Space detection** `File > Settings > Code Style | Indents Detection`

**To adjust tab / indent spacing** `File > Settings > Code Style > {Language}`